# Change from labialized velar to labial

Tags: phonology, phonetics

Is there a specific auditory reason for which a labiovelar such as "kʷ" becomes a "p" sound?This could also be applied to the change in Latin from "duellum" to "bellum"

Comment: The title sounded like the development from [w] to [β̞] to me, because [w] is equally labial and velar. [kʷ] has velar closure but only labial approximation.

Comment: @tobiornottobi You're right,I fixed it

Answer (score 5):

I would say you hear the labialization (I think a lower F2) and you hear the plosion. These features are shared with [b] and [p]. The lack of voicing of [k] is further shared with [p] and the voicing of [d] is shared with [b].

Comment: Low F2 is only observed with rounded labial. This can only be explained with an articulatory analysis, where some distinctive features are lost because of the principle of least effort.

Comment: @amegnunsen As far as I know, lip rounding also lowers the F2 of front vowels etc.

Comment: Yes, I am saying the same thing. You are talking about [p] and [b], but these consonants don't have rounded lips.

Comment: @amegnunsen Ah, okay. That's a good point. They don't have rounded lips but closed lips. And you are saying, closing the lips fully does not lead to a lowered F2. What I assumed was that lip rounding (especially compressed) and lip closure had similar acoustic properties and that after breaking the closure the lips are likely to not be spread. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: Perceptually, I don't think so. pʷ/bʷ are common sounds, so kʷ will become one of them instead of p/b.

Comment: @amegnunsen pʷ instead of a cluster pw? Which languages have that phoneme?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87676/discussion-between-tobiornottobi-and-amegnunsen).